# Adjusting Width Does Nothing

Tags: html, css

I would like to place the class `important` in the upper-right corner of the page and with a vertical scrollbar to control overflow. Changing the width of `important` does nothing, so the scrollbar currently is displaying, but does nothing as there is not overflow. Why is this happening?

```
<div class="important">
    <p>It's important to have some knowledge of CSS positioning. But
    you will <em>not</em> be an expert after just a few simple examples!</p>
</div>

div.important {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
overflow-y: scroll;
width: 50 px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the space of `width: 50px`

Answer (score 0):

`overflow-y: scroll;` will always display a scrollbar, even if there is nothing to scroll. Changing it to `overflow-y: auto;` should make sure there is only a scrollbar if there is overflow.